# AngularJS controller called every time after ngRoute url is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with below code. When I go to `main` controller url `#/`, `Angular` naturally calls main controller - it execute `AJAX` request. Problem is, that when I click `#/some-url`, and then `#/` url again, this AJAX request is executed again, which is not desired and unnecessary due to performance. I thought controllers are called only once, but it doesn't look like this is the case, at least with `ngRoute`.

```
angular.module('robotsApp', ['ngRoute', 'controllers'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        var root = '/static/js/partials/';
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: root + 'main.html',
                controller: 'main as main'
            }).
            when('/some-url', {
                templateUrl: root + 'some_template.html',
                controller: 'someController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);

angular.module('controllers', [])
    .controller('main', ['$http', function($http){
        $http.get('/user/recent-gain-loss').success(function(data){
            this.recent_gain_loss = data;
        }.bind(this));
    }]);

<p>{{ main.recent_gain_loss }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the data in to a value and then check if the data are already set.

```
angular.module('values', [])
.value('recentGainLoss', {})
angular.module('controllers', ['values'])
    .controller('main', ['$http', 'recentGainLoss', function($http, recentGainLoss){

        if (Object.keys(recentGainLoss).length < 1) {
          $http.get('/user/recent-gain-loss').success(function(data){
            recentGainLoss = angular.extend(recentGainLoss, data);

           });

        }
        this.recent_gain_loss = recentGainLoss;

    }]);
```

Comment: So I need to use service for that? Does angular always call controller connected with ngRoute url when corresponding url is clicked?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure but i think that it does (i shall look it ... in the code). Any way to hold state along the application it is better to abstract it to a service as is not the controller responsibility to hold any state. Besides you can share it on different components and be safe to state that you have the last version of the data

Comment: Btw, you have one literal in above code, angular does not have method extends, but extend :)